# Galaxy Nexus (GSM) will connect to adb, but is unrecognized on Mac (10.7.5)

Tags: eclipse, macos

I know there is already another question about galaxy nexus and macs, but it has not helped me.  Google's own website is completely useless as it says that on Mac "it just works" which is completely not true.  I am fairly certain that my phone is connecting to adb as it says there is a device it doesn't understand.  But there are no Mac drivers anywhere that I can see online.  This has been extremely frustrating.  How can I get my Galaxy Nexus to work as an AVD device for eclipse?

To clarify: I have tried many cables. I have removed EasyTether. I have banged my head against a wall.

Has this problem yet been truly solved?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) application to transfer files to the Galaxy Nexus on a Mac. As to using adb you need to activate USB debugging found in the Developer Options, which will not be visible on 4.2.x unless you activate it. This is done by going into:

> Settings -> About phone -> tapping Build number field 7 times.

I found this rather strange, but this is how it's done...